# Build MySQL table based on a LIKE from fields in another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm not sure if this is possible with an SQL query alone, but I basically want to create a table like this but with a condition on the course type field that stores 'futher' or 'higher' as a number based on what the 'course_type' is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses_index` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `further` int(1) NOT NULL,
      `higher` int(1) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      FULLTEXT `index` (title, url, course_type)
) AS SELECT title, url, course_type FROM `courses`
```

My `course_type` field on the courses table is a standard text field that will contain a string such as `"Higher, Further"` or `"Further"`.

I want to be able to say if this `course_type` field is `LIKE %higher%` then the value of the row is `1`. Likewise if the value of `course_type` is `LIKE %higher%further` then both fields are stored as a `1`, etc.

Is this possible by means of creating a temporary table, or a clever MySQL query?

Many thanks in advance

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
AS 
SELECT title, 
       url, 
       CASE
         WHEN course_type LIKE '%Further%' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as further,
       CASE
         WHEN course_type LIKE '%Higher%' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as higher
  FROM `courses`
```

EDIT fixed broken syntax

See also [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8bf/1)

Comment: Many thanks! The syntax was quite wrong there but I managed to work it out from what you've posted.

Comment: @Tim: should be fixed now (for others who might stumble across the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @beny23's answer I ended up with the following which works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses_index` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `course_type` int(2),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      FULLTEXT `index` (title, url, course_type)) 
AS
SELECT title, 
       url, 
       course_type,
       CASE
         WHEN course_type LIKE '%higher%further%' THEN 3
         WHEN course_type LIKE '%higher%' THEN 2
         WHEN course_type LIKE '%further%' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
  FROM `courses`
```